# How to iterate two lists simultaneously using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I below two lists

```
List<Map<String, Strings>> mapList
List<MyObject> myObjectList
```

Both lists have same size.

Currently I am iterating them using for loop as below.

```
List <CustomObject> customObjectList1 = new ArrayList();

List <CustomObject> customObjectList2 = new ArrayList();

int i=0;
for(MyObject myObject:myObjectList){
   if(“NEW”.equalIgnoreCase(myObject.getType)){
       customObjectList1.add(constructCustomObject(myObject, mapList.get(i));
   }
   if(“DELETE”.equalIgnoreCase(myObject.getType)){
       customObjectList2.add(constructCustomObject(myObject, mapList.get(i));
   }
   i++;
}
if(!customObjectList1.isEmpty()){
   jpaRepo.saveAll(customObjectList1);
}
if(!customObjectList2.isEmpty()){
   jpaRepo.deleteAll(customObjectList2);
}
```

Any better/efficient way to iterate two lists simultaneously using Java 8?

Comment: I would use an old-fashioned `for` loop, but this is fine.

Comment: Whatever you are doing is right, better go with old for loop, that has better performance. (int i = 0, i < len; i++) this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your issue centers in the ability of knowing the index of the object you are iterating on.

If you want to do it the stream way, maybe you can try something like this

**Disclaimer**: I do not think it will have a very big impact on performance since there are no objects that can be released by the GC, or decrease in number of iterations.

```java
IntStream.range(0, myObjectList.size())
  .forEach(idx -> {
     MyObject myObject = myObjectList.get(idx);
     if(“NEW”.equalIgnoreCase(myObject.getType)){
       customObjectList1.add(constructCustomObject(myObject, mapList.get(idx));
     }
     if(“DELETE”.equalIgnoreCase(myObject.getType)){
       customObjectList2.add(constructCustomObject(myObject, mapList.get(idx));
     }
  });
;
```